# Is it possible to view jQuery added data in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

When creating websites I often use jQuery's `.data()` function to add data to elements.

Is it possible to view all data which is stored with an element in Chrome?

So when I inspect an element it shows the data in Chrome itself.

If not would it be possible to write a plugin to 'extend' to Chrome `element inspector` to also show to data?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Open the inspector, and into the console, type

```
$('<some selector>').data()
```

and then hit return to evaluate the `data()` method and show its return value directly.

There's no need to use `console.log` unless you're calling it within non-interactive code.

Comment: This doesn't help me. I iterate over a number of div's that have the same class and store indivindual data to each. Now I want to see this data, but I can't select these div's individually using your approach, easily.

Comment: @Toni Try `$('<some selector>').map(function (el) { return el.data(); })`

Comment: Tip: if you select an element in the Elements window, it becomes **$0** in the console. Then you can enter `$($0).data()` Another tip:  see both Elements and Console in a split-screen with the [Esc key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32373994/673991).

Comment: BobStein-VisiBone: Magic! Couldn't find this info anywhere, and it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Agree with Wade Hatler. This is the second awesome tip for me today. The other being Chrome's 'Set as Global Variable' feature.

Answer (score 20):

## [Chrome Query](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-query/dbjmdgkkckmadopefnikhkpeaaojomaf?hl=en)

Can be found in the [Chrome Extensions Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-query/dbjmdgkkckmadopefnikhkpeaaojomaf?hl=en) and adds another tab to the properties panel in the developer tools.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Your answer should be the new accepted answer.

Comment: Extension does what it should. Realy confortable. The dev bar should be closed and reopened after install.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in the latest version of Chrome

Comment: Extension kind of works, but data fields don't update live as they change.

Answer (score 6):

Type into the chrome console:

```
console.log($('selector').data());
```

and it will list the `data` in that element

Comment: If executing this inside the consult, you can leave off the `console.log(…)` and just run `$('selector').data()`. The result will still be printed in the console.

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome Query](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/samples.html#924f75a201bb0ec8d6c0b1c9c88c679ea211c93d)

Answer (score 2):

For this reason, I don't use the `$(selector).data()` pattern, and, instead I use a more HTML natural `$(selector).attr('data-name','value')` which adds the values to the actual HTML.

`$(selector).attr('data-name','value')` does not work in IE8+ browsers. `.data()` is preferred. Also, a user defined var such as say: `data-name` is not an attribute in HTML.

Comment: Agreed, this is a way more discoverable pattern than 'data()'

Comment: I agree for the primitive data types but what about complex types?

Comment: I might argue that you should have a viewmodel, or a dataModel, depending on your patterns.  in knockout you can see the node context.  in other patterns you might only store an ID there and then look it up via delegation based on the ID.  there are even plugins for chrome that show the node context for Knockout in the debugger/inspector.