# jQuery: Create anchor with an object of data as a data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having problems creating an anchor with an object of data (patientData) as the data-patient attribute. The example blow shows what I'm trying to do. The jQuery docs state you can pass .data() an name and object, but I can't get it to set.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

I've tried many different ways. They don't use any .serialize() or JSON.stringify(). I assume it's a simple mistake or I am missing something important. Comments "//" are some of the old ways I've tried to set the 'data-patient' attribute to an object of data.

```
// Define patient data as object
var patientData = {};
if (appt.appt_id) patientData.appt_id = appt.appt_id;
if (appt.enc_id) patientData.enc_id = appt.enc_id;
if (appt.person_id) patientData.person_id = appt.person_id;

var patientAnchor = $('<a />', {
    href: myUrl,
    html: patientHtml,
    class: 'apptSet',
//    'data-patient': JSON.stringify(patientData),
//    'data-appt_id': (appt.appt_id) ? appt.appt_id : null,
//    'data-enc_id': (appt.enc_id) ? appt.enc_id : null,
//    'data-person_id': (appt.person_id) ? appt.person_id : null,
    'data-ajax': 'true'
}).data('patient', patientData);

console.log(patientAnchor);
```

**Edit:** I just noticed this example from:

http://api.jquery.com/data/

In the example they use a DIV with object data.

```
$( "div" ).data( "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the data property is not working? You have patientData as any empty object so if the appt properties are not defined, patientData will still be empty:

```
if (appt.appt_id) patientData.appt_id = appt.appt_id;
if (appt.enc_id) patientData.enc_id = appt.enc_id;
if (appt.person_id) patientData.person_id = appt.person_id;
```

Try doing the following to see the data for patient:

```
console.log(patientAnchor.data('patient'));
```

Also, try to set it statically and see if that works:

```
.data('patient', {appt_id: 12, enc_id: 23, person_id: 3);
```

Comment: Yes, the appt_id is always set. The other two are optional. I'll go run a JSFiddle with your suggestions.

Comment: Console.log() worked. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLeQ9/7/  But, how can I see the data from Google Chrome's "Inspect Element"? It doesn't show up in the element's HTML attributes or in the element properties. Or am I missing it? 'data-ajax' shows up under 'dataset: ajax'

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941725/is-it-possible-to-view-jquery-added-data-in-chrome