# Split the "Elements" tab and the "Console" in Chrome dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to have a view of both the Elements and the Console in two different windows or with the windows split in two part?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The Drawer offers the functionality you want. When on the elements panel, just press <kbd>esc</kbd> (when DevTools has focus) to open the drawer which contains a console.

Comment: And do you know if there is way to do that in an other window ? However its perfect :)

Comment: You can "undock" the DevTools. Search SO or Google and plenty of things will come up for that to show you how to do it.

Comment: `Esc` stands for Emerge semi-screen console. (Slaps forehead.)